# Ubuntu Loses Network Connectivity After Update

Tags: boot, networking, network-manager, dhclient

I am experiencing something truly alarming. I recently ran an update on a bunch of ubuntu servers, literally all sorts of machines, different processors, including 2 Raspberry Pis running Ubuntu. I ran the update, and then after I rebooted several of them, none came up. I stopped rebooting and began investigating. Apparently the machines came up, but networking was down. I spent some time researching and found out that the ethernet cables were all connected, however, when I executed `lshw -c network` I would get something like this:

```
  *-network DISABLED               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: I210 Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       logical name: enp5s0
       version: 03
       serial: d4:5d:df:09:b7:01
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=igb driverversion=5.6.0-k firmware=0. 6-5 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:17 memory:dc100000-dc11ffff ioport:b000(size=32) memory:dc120000-dc123fff
```

I did some more digging and found that I can bring networking back up with `dhclient <INTERFACE>` (so for the server shown above, it would be `dhclient enp5s0`).

The problem is that now, every time I reboot, I have to attach a monitor/keyboard to the server and manually execute this command to get networking back up. And I don't want to reboot any of my other servers that have yet to display this issue.

Does anyone know what's going on here? It almost feels like some kind of packaging error, like the update overrode some configuration that's supposed to be starting up networking on boot. The weird part is that this is affecting ALL my servers so far as I can tell - Intel, AMD, ARM. It also affects one machine I have that's running Ubuntu 21.10 with a GUI. I even tried booting with a previous kernel version and it also had issues. I am unable to reproduce the issue in a VM.

Please advise, thank you in advance.

P.S. I am somewhat worried if I am the only one getting this issue, but i have been unable to find a question on here experiencing the same problem. Is it possible that I am doing something on *all* my servers that is causing this? If so, why was it not an issue until now?

Comment: Look at the logs! `sudo  journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: I did. It was unhelpful. There was nothing about the actual problem.

Answer (score 2):

Alright, I figured out the problem. Turns out I deployed one of my own applications that conflicted with an apt-installed `python3-yaml`, so I uninstalled `python3-yaml` and installed it using pip. What I didn't realize is that this actually removed `netplan.io` which was dependent on `python3-yaml`.

Welp... at least its my own damn fault.